# Not able to capture data from an InputText inside a datatable in jsf

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have a `datatable` where I have two columns.

column 1 : output text, gets populated from bean data. 
coulmn 2 : input text boxes

I have made column1 as a `commandLink` on which I have attached an `actionListener`. The aim is that When i click on a row on UI the selected row data should be captured in bean.

here is the code :

```
<h:dataTable id="headerOverrides" styleClass="header" headerClass="headerTable"
  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:commandLink id="payment_Fund_Name" styleClass="header"
                    actionListener="#{pc_Billing.sortColumn}"
                    onmouseover="resetTargetFrame();">
                    <h:outputText style="width:150px" 
                      value="#{bundle.billing_Fund_Name}">                                                    
                    </h:outputText>
                </h:commandLink>
           </f:facet>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
           <f:facet name="header">
                <h:commandLink id="allocation_Percent" styleClass="header"
                    actionListener="#{pc_Billing.sortColumn}"
                    onmouseover="resetTargetFrame();">
                    <h:outputText style="width:65px" value="#{bundle.billing_Allocation_Percent}">
                    </h:outputText>
                </h:commandLink>                            
           </f:facet>
        </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2">
    <div class="divTable" style="height: 176px" id="overrideTableData">
    <h:dataTable id="overrideTable" value="#{pc_Billing.overrideFundsList}"
                var="currentRow" columnClasses="column" headerClass="header"
                    rowClasses="#{pc_Billing.paymentRowStyles}" binding="#{pc_Billing.allocationOverrideTable}"
                    styleClass="complexTable" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0"
                    width="100%" border="1" >


          <h:column id="override_Fund">
            <h:commandLink onmouseover="resetTargetFrame();" id="override_FundLink"
                            actionListener="#{pc_Billing.selectFromRow}" immediate="true"
                            styleClass="textTable" style="width:100%">
                     <h:outputText styleClass="textTable"
                               value="#{currentRow.fundName}" style="width:140px">
                      </h:outputText>
            </h:commandLink>
           </h:column>
           <h:column id="override_Allocation">
              <h:inputText id="allocation_Percent" styleClass="textInput" value="#{currentRow.allocation}"
                                disabled="#{!(pc_Billing.loanPayment || pc_Billing.universalLife)}" onblur="totalFrom();"
                                style="width:70px">
                  <f:convertNumber type="percent" />
              </h:inputText>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
```

The `selectFromRow` method from bean

```
public void selectFromRow(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getComponent().getId().equalsIgnoreCase("override_FundLink")) {
            paymentOverrideSelectedRow = (PaymentOverride) allocationOverrideTable.getRowData();
            allocationOverrideTableData.setFundName(paymentOverrideSelectedRow.getFundName());
            allocationOverrideTableData.setAllocation(paymentOverrideSelectedRow.getAllocation());

        }else if(e.getComponent().getId().equalsIgnoreCase("fundLink"))
        {
            preimumOverrideSelectedRow = (PremiumOverride) premiumOverrideTable.getRowData();
            premiumOverrideTableData.setFundName(preimumOverrideSelectedRow.getFundName());
            premiumOverrideTableData.setAmount(preimumOverrideSelectedRow.getAmount());
            premiumOverrideTableData.setEndDate(preimumOverrideSelectedRow.getEndDate());
            premiumOverrideTableData.setInterestRate(preimumOverrideSelectedRow.interestRate);
        }

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
    }
```

Now what is happening is that I am not getting the data from the input text boxes on table. it is null. What am I missing? 
Also when the `selectFromRow` function executes the table renders and the data I enter in text boxes is wiped out.

Comment: why don't you use `action="#{pc_Billing.selectFromRow(myVarOfTable)}"` ? just pass the row object to the action method `public void selectFromRow(someRowObject myObj) {` ?

Comment: @BalusC : please take a look now, is the code readable now?

Comment: @Daniel : what difference would that do? The present method do work. the problem was `immediate="true"` please refer to Szilagyi Donat`s answer below

Comment: That is how one should access row element using JSF... and you will be able to drop the `binding` (which is so JSF 1.X)

Comment: @Daniel yea what you say does look clean. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to remove the immediate="true" from here?

```
<h:commandLink onmouseover="resetTargetFrame();" id="override_FundLink"
               actionListener="#{pc_Billing.selectFromRow}" immediate="true"
               styleClass="textTable" style="width:100%">
```

I guess it makes running your selectFromRow method earlier than processing the value of the inputText.

Comment: You are right man.. that works. I can get the data. But now the problem is the immediate is not true. and it is going through all the validations etc. is there a solution for that?

Comment: Maybe embedding an f:ajax tag into h:commandLink the following way: `<h:commandLink ...><f:ajax execute="..."/></h:commandLink>` can help. The execute attribute you should refer to the id of the inputText field.

Comment: The project I am working on was recently upgraded from JSF1.2 to JSF2. the libraries were updated but the files still have a `.jsp` extension. So I am not able to use `ajax` :(

Comment: It is a bit primitive, but in difficult cases I usually remove bean validation from my entities and make it manually in the managed bean in a method what I can call when I want, typically when saving the record.